# Java 9 modules vs maven modules

Tags: java, maven, java-9

I have a maven project with different modules. And I like seeing different functionality in a different project , a maven sub module. And I feel it best to manage , because I can distribute these sub modules to different developers and they don’t even see any codes unnecessarily. In short for a developer working on a functionality, it’s clean .

Now honestly I don’t have experience in java 9. And I don’t know whether to use this feature in java 9. As we are re writing one project,I am exploring this in java9.

I believe java 9 is more of destination centric , meaning we generate a light weight byte code so that if someone doesn’t need a module doesn’t need to run it.  But because all modules are  in one project, developer can see codes which he doesn’t need to .

And specially because I don’t need versions to be maintained for sub modules, should I be using java9 ?
Can someone please throw some light here.

Comment: *"And I didn’t find a good reason to use this feature in java 9."* - Well don't.  *"But I always like to upgrade and replace with some cool codes."* - That is NOT a good reason.  Bottom line. Figure out if there is a reason to use modules **first**.

Comment: Well , actually we are rewriting a code base ,that said I implement all newer versions and thus trying to compare.